# In Maya- how can I merge mulitple primitive cubes together into one parent item? (And is this actually needed for using in unity etc)?

Tags: 3d, 3d-meshes, maya, rigid-body-dynamics, 3d-modeling

Im trying to make some 3d models in Maya and then put them into Unity as characters which I can give rigidbody to etc. (Im new to Unity and 3d modelling software, but i have a small amount of programming experience in LWJGL,  LibGDX  and XNA).

I'm focusing on making some assets out of blocks. To give a kind of 2.5D feel to a platform game.

I have made the following image but as you'll see its just a bunch of cubes. I think i need this to be turned into a single piece (but im not sure if 100% necessary or not). Of course, I will be adding animation to this by way of moving the blocks about for different frames of animation.

As I said, im very new to this so I may be doing things completely wrong.

Heres the image:

[image]

What i need is to be able to refer to this as one piece with its own transform position, scale etc that I can adjust. Currently if I select it all and try to change the scale it only changes on of the cubes scale even when all are selected.

Also once I've created this and want to add it to my game in unity, will each cube get a rigidbody when i add it or will the whole item get it as standard?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What I was taught to do was remove the faces that are inside the image, and then connect the vertices around the edges to make it into one cohesive piece. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Combining-separating-and-splitting-Merge-vertices-edges-or-faces-into-one-vertex-htm.html

Comment: ah, so manually go through each edge? that may take a long while on complex designs. Is there any way to make any edge touching another edge merge?

Comment: You can do it based off edges or off vertices, you have to do them bit by bit because if you try to merge them all at once they'll merge onto an average point and ruin the model

Comment: oh damn! so basically i need to learn how to blend the sides as I go

Comment: another thing i need to still understand if u can help... If I create a model in this way, then export it to unity, will Unity see it as a complete model or a bunch of cubes?

Comment: Unity *should* see it as a complete model, granted it's *actually* a complete model. If none of the pieces are connected they won't be in Unity.

Comment: i dont think they are connected. I've been trying to follow your Edit Mesh > Merge tut attached, but it seems to have no affect. I could move it as one, but I see no reference to it being parented, or a name given to the piece as a whole. Also i can still see lines between the blocks.

Comment: also when i try the other of the two methods, it says to open the Marking Menu and click Merge Vertices but there is no such option there when i use SHIFT-RMB

Comment: how do i connect the pieces

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HiKvP-fmUM you need to select vertices, go to edit mesh, merge and then play with the threshold so they don't merge too far. You know it works when there's only one vertex and not two.

Comment: thanks for this. I actually have managed to get the menu to pop up. I rightclick over to Vertex, then holding shift and RMB over the actual Vertices i want (i think Vertices means sides) and then I get option to Merge Verticies. I've done it for all the verticies that needed it, but how do i know that I have actually accomplished it. The model and menus seem unaltered

Comment: If they've properly merged you won't be able to drag a vertex and have it separate it should move the whole but it's connected with and there won't be gaps in the edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was taught to do in Maya was to first remove faces that are inside of the model. These are unnecessary and up the poly count for unused faces. You can do this by selecting faces with the RMB and using delete on the desired faces.

You'll next want merge based off edges or off vertices.

Use the RMB again and choose vertices or edges, select all the ones you wish to merge, go to edit mesh, and hit merge.

You have to do them bit by bit because if you try to merge them all at once they'll merge onto an average point and ruin the model. You can alter how close they merge together by changing the threshold.

Try [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=-HiKvP-fmUM) for assistance as well. You know it works when there's only one vertex and not two. You can also tell that by selecting a single vertex (that you intended to merge to) and dragging it around. If they've properly merged you won't be able to drag a vertex and have it separate into two, and it should move the whole side, and there won't be gaps in the edges (if you drag it away you won't suddenly see inside the model).

Notes based off some comments you made:

- There won't be a parenting structure that you can see changed like Unity has.
- When you import it into Unity, Unity *should* see it as a complete model, granted it's *actually* a complete model. If none of the pieces are connected, they won't be in Unity.
- It's good to do this as you go but it's not necessary.
- I was actually taught to build based off one item. So start with a cube and just build from there, so that you're not doing this cut and merge etc. This basically involves adding vertices to the cube and pulling them out to grow the original cube into the model you want.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. You've really helped me with some details of how it works. As it happens i started making a few things and just importing straight to unity and it helped me visualise how things get imported. I'm a long way off producing something really nice, but im a step further than i was before I visited here so cheers pal!